# How to generate a numbered table with uniform distribution of numbers?

Tags: tables, exam, nicematrix

I want to generate a table for multiple choices with the following requirements

1. Numbers are distributed uniformly on `\linewidth`
2. Dot separators of numbers are aligned between rows
3. Ability to customize the numbers easily
4. Ability to determine how many entries for each row (e.g., 1-5 on one row then 6-10 on the next)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcounter{choicenum}
\setcounter{choicenum}{0}

\newcommand{\postMultipleChoiceTable}{

\noindent%
{\bfseries Answers to Multiple Choice Questions}

\noindent%
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{@{}X[l, t] @{\stepcounter{choicenum}}X[l, t] @{\stepcounter{choicenum}}X[l, t] @{\stepcounter{choicenum}}X[l, t] @{\stepcounter{choicenum}}X[l, t] @{\stepcounter{choicenum}}X[l, t] @{\stepcounter{choicenum}}X[l, t] @{\stepcounter{choicenum}}X[l, t] @{\stepcounter{choicenum}}X[l, t] @{\stepcounter{choicenum}}X[l, t]@{}}
    
    \toprule
    
    \stepcounter{choicenum}\phantom{1}\arabic{choicenum}. & \phantom{1}\arabic{choicenum}. & \phantom{1}\arabic{choicenum}. & \phantom{1}\arabic{choicenum}. & \phantom{1}\arabic{choicenum}. & \phantom{1}\arabic{choicenum}. & \phantom{1}\arabic{choicenum}. & \phantom{1}\arabic{choicenum}. & \phantom{1}\arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}.
    \\
    
    \stepcounter{choicenum}\arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}. & \arabic{choicenum}.
    \\
    
    \stepcounter{choicenum}\arabic{choicenum}. & & & & & &  & & &
    \\
    
    \bottomrule
    
\end{NiceTabularX}

}

\begin{document}

\postMultipleChoiceTable

\end{document}
```

The code above works, but not optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- added packages `etoolbox` and `pgffor`
- defined command `\createtabledata` that is used for automatically creating the table content
- `\postMultipleChoiceTable`

  - has now two arguments:

    - #1 = number of columns -> `\numOfCols`
    - #2 = number of questions -> `\numOfQuestions`
  - defined table columns with `*{\numOfCols}{ X[l, t] @{} }`
  - use `\setcounter{choicenum}{0}` within the command

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcounter{choicenum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\createtabledata}{%
    \def\tabledata{}%
    \pgfmathparse{ceil(\numOfQuestions/\numOfCols)}% calculate number of lines
    \foreach \j in {1, ..., \pgfmathresult} {% lines
        \foreach \i in {1, ..., \numOfCols} {% columns
            \global\stepcounter{choicenum}%
            \protected@xappto\tabledata{%
                \ifnumless{\arabic{choicenum}}{\numOfQuestions+1}{%
                    \ifnumless{\arabic{choicenum}}{10}{%
                        \phantom{1}%
                    }{}%
                    \arabic{choicenum}.%
                }{}%
                \ifnumless{\i}{\numOfCols}{&}{\\}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
    \tabledata%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\postMultipleChoiceTable}[2]{
    % #1 = number of columns
    % #2 = number of questions
    \def\numOfCols{#1}
    \def\numOfQuestions{#2}
    %
    \setcounter{choicenum}{0}
    
    \medskip
    \noindent%
    {\bfseries Answers to Multiple Choice Questions}
    
    \noindent%
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{@{} *{\numOfCols}{ X[l, t] @{} } @{}}
        \toprule
        \createtabledata
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabularX}
}

\begin{document}

\postMultipleChoiceTable{10}{21}
\postMultipleChoiceTable{6}{20}
\postMultipleChoiceTable{5}{3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you